# Bluebird promise not being resolved in IE 9/10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, promise, bluebird

Preconditions:
I have index.php page. I dynamically add new iframe element to the generated page with src 'index.php' - so inside my basic page the same page is being rendered (except its being initialized in the other way). My index.php page includes index.js file that has some wrapper functions for interaction with my API. Wrapper function returns Bluebird's promise. https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md

When I want to get some data from API I use my wrapper function in this manner: `MyApp.API.get('/url', queryParams).then().caught()`. That code works fine in Chrome/FF/Safari/IE8+

However, when I try to use that code in IE9/10 (remember, I have an iframe with the same src), and wrapper function is being called from inside an iframe, my promise is neither being resolved nor being thrown any exception which can be caught.

I have no idea what can cause such a strange behaviour as wrapper function is being widely used across application. What is more weird is that IE8/11 works absolutely fine.

I understand that its hard to help as there is such a little information provided by me. However, if anyone can suggest me something - that would be great.

Comment: Can you create a sample test case on jsbin or stack snippets?

Comment: What is this "wrapper function" (code), what does it wrap around? Also, how are you "calling it from inside an iframe"?

Comment: IE9/10 has some iframe issues introduced to fix an IE8 memory leak. If this is a Bluebird issue on the other hand I definitely want to know and I'm sure Petka does too. It would be a great help if you reduced your problem further.